# Typescript Unable to resolve signature of parameter of decorator in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs

I'm getting the error when I'm decorating the class in nestjs service.

The Typescript is compiling without errors, and I'm getting this problem only in VSCode.

```
Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
  Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'.ts(1239)
```

My tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}
```

My Class

```
export class AuthService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger('AuthService');
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly prisma: PrismaService,
    private readonly passwordService: PasswordService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly twilioService: TwilioService,
    private readonly userService: UsersService,
    @InjectQueue('nest-worker') private nestWorkerQueue: Queue,
    @InjectQueue('mailsend') private mailSend: Queue,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) protected readonly cacheManager: Cache,
    private readonly mailerService: MailService
  ) {}
```

I tried reinstalling typescript removing node modules, but the problem persists.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using and what config?

Comment: I'm using 4.9.4 config is in the post

Comment: what if you use the tsc of your project instead of VSC? via `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"` to `.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: I'm getting the same result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your extensions. For me remove "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" extension solved this problem.

Comment: I had to select correct typescript version in vs code

Answer (score 8):

i've encountered the same issue with this error: "Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1". 
and the fix that worked for me was:

1. open the vscode command palette
2. enter "Select TypeScript Version"
3. choose "use workspace version"

Comment: this worked for me. In my case vs code typescript version is 5.2.2 and worspace typescript version is 4.3.5. So after selecting workspace version, it works well.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to resolve this issue are:

1. Open a JavaScript or TypeScript file in VS Code.
2. In the VS Code command palette, run the TypeScript: Select TypeScript version command.
3. Make sure you have Use VS Code's version selected

The steps above are explained in the **JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly** details tab:

[image: select typescript version to use]

Answer (score 0):

it seems according to [Microsoft changelog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#more-accurate-type-checking-for-parameter-decorators-in-constructors-under-experimentaldecorators#more-accurate-type-checking-for-parameter-decorators-in-constructors-under-experimentaldecorators) in typescript 5 there is `More Accurate Type-Checking for Parameter Decorators in Constructors Under --experimentalDecorators`, I couldn't downgrade my typescript and [This answer](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/aurelia-v1-issue-with-decorators-and-typescript-5/5163/4) worked for me.

I had this code:

```js
  constructor(@InjectMapper() mapper: Mapper) {
    super(mapper);
  }
```

```js
  constructor(@((InjectMapper as any)()) mapper: Mapper) {
    super(mapper);
  }
```

so maybe this will solve your problem:

```js
@((Inject as any)(CACHE_MANAGER)) protected readonly cacheManager: Cache,
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the easiest solution was to enable  decorators

{
"compilerOptions": {
"experimentalDecorators": true
}
}

Comment: The ts.config shown in the question already has experimentalDecorators enabled.