# Unable to resolve signature of WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER parameter decorator when called as an expression

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, winston, nest-winston

## Context

I have been working on this project for almost a year now, with no issue injecting Winston logger `Logger` with the `WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER` token. I woke up last week to find that TypeScript now highlights this piece of code `@Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER)` as red, with this message:

> Unable to resolve signature of parameter decorator when called as an expression.
> Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol'.ts(1239)
>
> --
>
> (alias) const WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER: "winston"
>
> import WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER
>
> --
>
> No quick fixes available

Thinking it was VSCode, I closed the project to work on other things. Voila, I opened the project earlier today and it is still right there, staring me in the face. And the only thing I have updated so far is my VSCode.

However, thankfully, the project runs as usual.

## Code snippet

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston';
import { Logger } from 'winston';
//...

@Injectable()
export class QueryTransactionsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger,
    //...
  ) {}

  //...
}
```

## Specs

### Relevant dependencies

- vscode: 1.77.0
- node: 16.13.0
- @nestjs/common: ^9.0.0
- typescript: ^4.3.5
- @types/node: ^16.0.0
- ts-node: ^10.0.0
- winston: ^3.8.2
- nest-winston: ^1.7.0

### TS Config

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  }
}
```

## Resolution Attempts

None of the below attempts worked to resolve this issue:

1. Restart VSCode
2. Reinstall all packages using `npm i`
3. Run audit fix using `npm audit fix`
4. Update `TypeScript: Enable Prompt Use Workspace Tsdk` to `true` on VSCode settings. Ref: [Typescript Unable to resolve signature of parameter of decorator in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227100/typescript-unable-to-resolve-signature-of-parameter-of-decorator-in-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your workspace version of typescript saved as dev-dependency in your project.
If there is no dev dependency of typescript in your project then open your project and in the path where you have node_modules add one by this command:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript@^4.3.5
```

Now:

1. Open VS Code Workspace Settings (F1 > Open Workspace Settings)
2. In search textbox search for "typescript.tsdk"
3. You will see a setting with title: **TypeScript: Tsdk** and a **textbox** in the bottom
4. In that textbox Update/Insert "./node_modules/typescript/lib"